# Version mismatch between H2O and R package, where to get the right one?

Tags: h2o

I am using H2O (basic version) and it works well. I want to try Deep Water for GPU support. So, I carefully followed the instruction on;
https://www.h2o.ai/deep-water/#try
to install Deep Water. However, it failed to run and showed this error:

> Error in h2o.init(nthreads = -1, port = 54323, startH2O = FALSE) :
>         Version mismatch! H2O is running version 3.15.0.393 but h2o-R package is version 3.13.0.369.
>                Install the matching h2o-R version from - http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/(HEAD detached at c46596cad)

Where do I get the right version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can force the Connection

h2o.init(ip=Cluster_ip, port = Cluster_port,

strict_version_check = FALSE,

startH2O = FALSE)

Comment: Thank you, it is useful answer

Answer (score 4):

According to the deep-water link, it wants you to use 3.13.0. And your error message is saying you are using the 3.13.0.369 R package.

So, I think the problem is that you have 3.15.0.393 already running on this machine. Kill it and try again.

From inside your current R session, `h2o.shutdown()` *might* work. If not, and you using unix, do something like `ps auxw | grep h2o` to find its PID and kill it; if using Windows search for h2o in the task manager. Or, cleanest, if you know you have an R (or Python, etc.) client where you started that 3.15.0 version of H2O, go and close that client.

Comment: Thank you @Darren, you are absolutely right. I found that the information on the website for Deep Water installation was not up to date.